# How to set right Alt to work as a Win(Super) key?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Although there are lots of different articles how to change the left Alt to simulate win , I want to map the right Alt to do so.  I want to move to 11.10, I fall back to unity 2d and dont have a win key. I kennot even get the keycode in the articles I found...
Any help or good suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [xmodmap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xmodmap) to remap any
key on the keyboard; in particular, you can remap the *right Alt* to
act as a *Super/Win* key.

Create a file named `.Xmodmap` in your home directory with the
following content:

```
! free up right-Alt for remapping
remove mod1 = Alt_R

! Right-Alt remapped to Super
clear mod4
keycode 108 = Super_R
add mod4 = Super_R
```

When you log out and then log in again, GNOME should ask you if you
want to load the `.Xmodmap` file; answer "yes" and you're ready to
go. (You will only asked once.)

Alternatively, you can load the `.Xmodmap` configuration from a
terminal at any time:

```
xmodmap .Xmodmap
```

There are a few things that can vary depending on the X server version and keyboard model. The following items could help you adapt the `.Xmodmap` file to your specific environment.

1. Check that your *right Alt* key is initially on *mod1*: Issue the command
   `xmodmap` in a terminal window, and you should get an output *like*
   this one:

   ```
   xmodmap:  up to 3 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

   shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
   lock        Caps_Lock (0x9),  Caps_Lock (0x4e)
   control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
   mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Alt_L (0xcc)
   mod2      
   mod3        Mode_switch (0xcb)
   mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce)
   mod5
   ```

   If the `Alt_R` tag does not appear in the *mod1* line but on a
   different one, adjust your `.Xmodmap` accordingly.
2. Check that your *right Alt* key is keycode 108: in a terminal window,
   type the command [xev](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xev), then focus
   the small square window that popped up.  If you type the *right
   Alt* key there, you should see lines appearing in the terminal
   window.  Look for a stanza like this one:

   ```
   KeyPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
       root 0xbd, subw 0x5000002, time 867397196, (53,48), root:(54,49),
       state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
       XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
       XFilterEvent returns: False
   ```

   The number after the `keycode` word is the one you want in your
   `.Xmodmap` file for remapping *right Alt*.

Comment: Thank you. I can keep my left all for all the things I need.

Comment: strange, although the solution used to work, now it stopped??? When I restart the PC and recreate the solution, it works until the next restart...

Comment: @deckoff It means that your `.Xmodmap` file is not being read at the start of the X session.  Try adding `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to your `.gnomerc` (or equivalent) file.

Comment: I will try it. It seems it does not work when password login is disabled. If I see a login screen( no matter if I log out and I am logging in, or if I have enabled password login at start it will work).Please look [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1869618) if you are willing to help. It seems the file is loaded, but not executed properly.

Comment: Yes, adding xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap to  .gnomerc worked

Comment: The mapping only worked properly for me when I set `keycode 108 = Super_R Super_R Super_R Super_R` (4 times, to account for the modified options)

Answer (score 3):

I found that simply:

```
remove mod1 = Alt_R
add mod4 = Alt_R
```

works as hoped. Am I missing any "gotchas" with this method?