# How do I swap mouse buttons to be left handed from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, mouse

I am left handed person.
Therefore I want to interchange the typical mouse buttons for right and left clicks.

I want to do this **via terminal**. May someone please suggest the command for it?

Is it possible to interchange these clicks at the **login screen** also? I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1"
```

in a terminal should work. If you want to run that command at the start of lightdm (the default login screen), you can edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151467/how-can-i-get-a-command-to-run-before-login-ie-while-booting-or-just-after/151479#151479) - use the `xmodmap` command instead of `xbacklight` in the script, of course.

Comment: this works for the present session.. how to make it permanent???

Comment: It should be permanent if you put it in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. If not, you can put it in Startup Applications or create a .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart from the terminal.

Comment: I have no /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file. Is there somewhere template for it?

Comment: This answer should contain a warning that `xmodmap` is global i.e. if you have a different pointing device like a graphic tablet or an air mouse, it will also be affected.

Answer (score 31):

You can use also `xinput` to do this.

It will switch the buttons on one mouse only.

First use-

```
xinput list
```

To see where you mouse is will be somthing like

```
"USB Mouse"     id=12       [slave pointer]
```

So use the id number for the next command to switch the button assignment.

```
xinput set-button-map 12 3 2 1
```

So, you would switch out 12 with the id number of your mouse.

Source: [1](http://ao2.it/en/blog/2010/01/19/poor-mans-multi-touch-using-multiple-mice-xorg)

Comment: I find this useful because I often have two mice, left and right. This technique allows them to be set to be the mirror image of each other.

Comment: And then you can make this permanent by creating a Xorg device configuration as explained here: http://linus.haxx.se/2013/03/07/mouse-button-mapping-in-xorg-conf/

Comment: or just a startup script if you wish

Comment: In case my pointer devices change IDs, I look up the ID as part of the command line:


**xinput set-button-map $(xinput list  --id-only "Kensington      Kensington Expert Mouse") 3 2 1**


The string in quotes comes from "xinput list" above.

Comment: This should be marked as answer rather than using xmodmap

Comment: You can use device name instead of device Id, like `xinput get-button-map 'USB Optical Mouse'`.

Answer (score 16):

`xmodmap` is the command to **change the mouse button mapping**:

`xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1"`

will remap the first three buttoons, left, middle and right, to act like , right, middle and left - not actually changing the middle button mapping.

That applies the change to the current session - more precisely, to the current X display, for exanple `:0`.

To save the **change persistent** over sessions, put the mapping into the file

`~/.Xmodmap`

If it does not exist, create it, like`touch ~/.Xmodmap`

Edit it to add the line

`pointer = 3 2 1`

If there already is a `pointer` line, it may have some function, of course; Instead of replacing it, better modify the first three values - keeping a comment with the old:

For example,

```
pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 16 17 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 6 7 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

becomes

```
!pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 16 17 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 6 7 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
pointer = 3 2 1 4 5 16 17 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 6 7 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

I'm used to `~/.Xmodmap` allways just working; But see [.Xmodmap works only when automatic login disabled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72064/xmodmap-works-only-when-automatic-login-disabled) if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

A full solution would look something like this:

```sh
device_id=$(xinput list | grep "Vert.*Mouse" | cut -f2 | cut -c4-)
xinput set-button-map $device_id 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8
```

## Full Answer

Using `xmodmap` affects all pointer devices. To make that change per device name you need to use `xinput` (as described by Mateo) but the device ID on `xinput list` might change for number of reasons so to make it work correctly each time you need to dynamically get the correct device ID on startup.

For example:

```sh
# find your device ID on the list
xinput list

# check the current buttons map:
xinput get-button-map $your_device_id

# find the problematic buttons
# press ctrl+c when done
xinput --test $your_device_id
```

My device name is `Logitech MX Vertical Ergonomic Mouse` and I need to switch places on buttons `4` and `5` in a following button map:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

So to get the device ID reliably I use:

```
xinput list | grep "Vert.*Mouse" | cut -f2 | cut -c4-
```

- `xinput list` - spits out device names and IDs
- `grep "Vert.*Mouse"` - finds the line containing `Vert` and `Mouse`
- `cut -f2` - cuts second "field" from that line, i.e. `id=17`
- `cut -c4-` - cuts from the 4th "character", i.e. `17`

Now that I have the command that always spits out the correct device ID, I can put it in parentheses like so: `$(command)` - it runs the command in a subshell and replaces it with its output. So a full one-liner that can be placed in a starting script looks as mentioned in **TL;DR**.

Answer (score 0):

Mateo's answer is right, but I wanted to present another way to set up this configuration with `xinput`.

It will also switch the buttons on one mouse only.

First list your devices:

```sh
xinput list
```

Your mouse will show up in this list somewhere:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ...
⎜   ↳ USB Mouse                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ...
```

Use the id number of your device for the next commands to switch the button assignment.
Verify that your device has a setting to enable Left-Handed mode:

```sh
xinput list-props 11                            
Device 'USB Mouse':
    Device Enabled (155):   1
    ...
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (311): 0
    ...
```

As you can see, that is property number `311`. It's an `8`-bit number with values `0` or `1`.
Now we can enable/disable that for your device:

```sh
xinput set-int-prop 11 311 8 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Execute this code in command prompt, it will remove and reset Optical mouse and touchpad to default- left click is for clicking and right click is for options.

```
modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Answer (score -1):

### For Ubuntu ~12.04 and prior

```
#!/usr/local/bin/tcsh -fb

# switches between right and left mouse
set leftMouseHand = `gconftool-2 --get /desktop/gnome/peripherals/mouse/left_handed`
if ( "$leftMouseHand" == "false" ) then
    gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/peripherals/mouse/left_handed true --type boolean
    gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/peripherals/mouse/cursor_theme Oxygen_White_Big --type string
else
    gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/peripherals/mouse/left_handed false --type boolean
    gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/peripherals/mouse/cursor_theme Oxygen_White_Big --type string
endif
```