# How to map <Right Alt> to <Left Alt> + <F1>?

Tags: unity, 13.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Putting the following into a `.xbindkeysrc` makes my keyboard irresponsive after reboot, with only control keys responding:

```
"{ echo KeyStrPress Alt_L; echo KeyStr F1; echo KeyStrRelease Alt_L; } | xmacroplay :0"
  Release+F13
```

I know the `xmacroplay` works because I've executed it at the command line, and also, executing `xbindkeys` to map, for example, <kbd>F2</kbd>, without rebooting, works as expected. So, first, I have a problem after rebooting, because of that I had to remove the `.xbindkeysrc` file.

I was in the *hard* process of trying to create the simple mapping of <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> to <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> in the system. I was going to use `xbindkeys` to map <kbd>F13</kbd> to  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and [`xmodmap`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70931/how-to-set-right-alt-to-work-as-a-winsuper-key) to map <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> to <kbd>F13</kbd>...

How do I map <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> to <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> so that I get hide/unhiding of the Launcher with a single key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, by default, <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut is not for hide/unhide the Launcher. This shortcut is used to give keyboard-focus to the Launcher. This means: gives keyboard-focus to the Launcher so it can be navigated with the cursor-keys. If you don't trust me, run the following command in terminal:

```
gsettings get org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ keyboard-focus
```

Now, to change <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut with another one, you can use the following command:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ keyboard-focus 'new_shortcut'
```

For example, to change it to <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, use:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ keyboard-focus '<Mod5>F1'
```

This works for mykeyboard (I mean "<Mod5>" for <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> key). I'm not sure for other keyboards as far as I can't test at the moment.

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/53092/gnome-map-altgr-key-to-alt

Comment: thanks, with your help, I was able to keyboard-focus by <Mod3> solely, which I've set as <Alt_R> through xmodmap. But, this setting works for unhiding the Launcher with keyboard focus, which is nice, but the old <Alt>F1 also hided the Launcher, and still does it, my <Mod3> setting doesn't hide the Launcher, just unhides. So <Alt>F1 doesn't unhide the Launcher anymore, now <Mod3> does it,  but <Alt>F1 does hide it, and <Mod3> doesn't. Any help to make <Mod3> also hide it?

Comment: Well, Esc is working for the unhide (by removing the focus), as I'm used to it, right now I'm almost fine with this, but I'd like to know whether I could get <Mod3> for hide and unhide of the Launcher.

Comment: I've put Super_R at Mod3 instead of Alt_R and now, the right Super is both hiding as unhiding the Launcher, I'll accept the answer but how I finished this mapping may be worth information in the answer itself. I have removed Super_R from Mod4, clear Mod3 and added Super_R to Mod3 at my `.Xmodmap`. I've added `xmodmap .Xmodmap` to session applications, and used the gsettings trick to map Mod3 to keyboard-focus. The End.